# Category filtering with combination of Not and Include Low Seg2Cat

Tags: categories, filtering

I have the following code which doesn't showing any result if I combine these two together, is this the correct syntax?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="people" orderby="date" category="{segment_3_category_id}&not51"   sort="desc"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the inclusion *and* exclusion of categories with the native channel:entries tag in a single parameter is not possible. The syntax you're using is therefore not supported.

You would either need to re-think your setup, use a custom query, or use [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) and its [Categories filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories), so you can use parameters like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    channel="people"
    orderby="date"
    category:group1="{segment_3_category_id}"
    category:group2="not 51"
    sort="desc"
}
```